# Java sendmail doesn't quite work (novel approach)

Tags: java, sendmail

Thanks in advance for being my second set of eyes on this. This is how I send emails and I'm not sure what I changed that broke it.

```
import java.io.*;
String msg = "From:sender@em.ail\nTo:\"First Last\"<my@em.ail>\nSubject:Test Mail\n\nBlah Blah Blah\n.\n";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(mail);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(p.getInputStream()));
pw.print(msg);
while (br.ready()) {System.out.println(br.readLine());}
```

The truly perplexing thing is that if I print out **msg** and paste it into a terminal window after running 'sendmail -t' The email sends just fine. I'm using putty on windows 7 and my IDE is RSA 8.0.4 . The server is running Solaris of some sort. I have nothing personally against installing a library to handle mailing, but getting anything installed around here is a herculean task.

---

As per everyone's suggestions the code now looks like this

```
import java.io.*;
String msg = "From:sender@em.ail\r\nTo:my@em.ail\r\nSubject:Test Mail\r\n\r\nBLAH BLAH BLAH\r\n.\r\n";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(mail);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
pw.print(msg);
pw.close();
```

and still doesn't work. Tried doing a buffered read from "getErrorStream()" and nothing came back.

Comment: For java it is better to use java mail. Your approach is system dependent.

Comment: As first step of debugging I would read error stream and input stream in two separate threads and then take things forward from there.

Comment: The line terminator in mail and all other Internet protocols is `\r\n`, not just `\n`. You need to close `pw` before the reads, and get rid of the `ready()` test.

Comment: @ACV could you suggest a more system agnostic method? Under the circumstances (no third party libraries) this seems like a decent compromise to me.

Comment: @EJP tried your suggestions to no effect. 
Why did you think the ready() test would cause an issue?

Comment: It causes an issue because it isn't correct. You need to read the entire response, not just the part that is available without blocking. You need to loop while `readLine()` isn't returning null. And you need to tell us what the response was.

Comment: Thanks, that was the last thing that needed fixing.

Comment: That and the line separators.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem turned out to be a combination of a typo in the string **mail** and the fact that **ready()** doesn't do what I thought it does. The typo was causing an error and one of the readers was blocking. Fixing the typo or removing the InputReader fixed it so, the new version does both.

Answer (score 0):

Try JavaMail. You will need to put some jars in the classpath though. Also you will need a smtp server credentials.

- [JavaMail Tutorial 1](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_sending_email.htm)
- [JavaMail Tutorial 2](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/java/mail/usingjavamail)

Comment: Thanks, but this is a big corporation and I'd rather not wait the six weeks it will take to get that request past the security review board.

Comment: Try:  flush() on PrintWriter because it is not activated by default

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
import java.io.*;
String msg = "From:sender@em.ail\r\nTo:my@em.ail\r\nSubject:Test Mail\r\n\r\nBLAH BLAH BLAH\r\n.\r\n";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(mail);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
pw.print(msg);
pw.flush();
pw.close();
```

or this:

```
import java.io.*;
String msg = "From:sender@em.ail\r\nTo:my@em.ail\r\nSubject:Test Mail\r\n\r\nBLAH BLAH BLAH\r\n.\r\n";
Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(mail);
PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(p.getOutputStream());
pw.println(msg);
pw.flush();
pw.close();
```

Comment: Also check exitValue of p

Comment: What is mail here: Process p = Runtime.getRuntime().exec(mail); ?

Comment: Sorry about that, "mail" is a string "/usr/sendmail -t"